# @font-face only works on IE, not on chrome

Tags: css, font-face

Currently i'm working on my first project in hmtl and css w/ bootstrap.
Until now, things are going pretty well. But now I have a problem with adding a custom font to my webpage. I searched how to do this but @font-face doesn't really work. My teacher fixed it in class so it should be possible I only don't know how he perfectly did it and he didn't give the code. I did the next:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Impact Label';
 src: url('ImpactLabel.eot');
 src: url('ImpactLabel.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('ImpactLabel.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('ImpactLabel.woff') format('woff')

 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

I saw that chrome support woff so I don't get why it doesn't work on chrome, it does work on IE though. My h1 looks just like this:

```css
h1
{
 font-family: 'Impact Label';
}
```

Any help is welcome. Link to website is [here](http://favoritevlogs.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: In your example, a semicolon is missing after `('woff')`. Could that be the reason?

Comment: How could I not see that...
It works now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a semi-colon after the last src property. The code should read:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Impact Label';
 src: url('ImpactLabel.eot');
 src: url('ImpactLabel.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('ImpactLabel.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('ImpactLabel.woff') format('woff');

 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```